# How to Convert ActiveRecord_Relation to an normal array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

I have an model which returns an active record relation. How to convert this active record relation into an normal ruby array?

Comment: Just put `.to_a` on the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relation has `to_a` method, which does exactly that. It is used internally for methods like `any?`

Answer (score 5):

If you need an array of one or more model attributes for your relation, then you can just use [ActiveRecord::Calculations#pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck).

From the docs:

```
Person.pluck(:id)
# SELECT people.id FROM people
# => [1, 2, 3]

Person.pluck(:id, :name)
# SELECT people.id, people.name FROM people
# => [[1, 'David'], [2, 'Jeremy'], [3, 'Jose']]
```

And there's more what you can do.